# Every time I open excel vba with alt f11 new projects appear, "unable to record" in office 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue that every time when I open Microsoft excel visual basic projects via <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f11</kbd> to edit the visual basic code, all I get are new projects. When I close it with <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> and reopen it with alt + f11 new projects appear, but I don't see my workbooks anywhere.

I tried repairing office via the control panel, but nothing worked. When I press record macro I get "unable to record"

**First-time <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f11</kbd> on a new blank workbook**

The following images are what follows after pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f11</kbd> and then <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>

*3 projects, no workbooks*
[image: 3 projects, no workbooks]

*7 projects no workbooks*
[image: 7 projects no workbooks]

*11 projects no workbooks*
[image: 11 projects no workbooks]

Adding modules to these projects have no effects.
Recording macros doesn't work.
Macros are enabled in the settings

[image: macros enabled]

But still, it doesn't work. How can I make worksheets appear in visual basic? Add my own visual basic code? This is currently thoroughly broken.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of googling and trying out various other things, I found that this is a bug introduced in windows 10 in this answers.microsoft.com thread.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/unable-to-run-excel-vba-record-macro-in-office/c881748a-9f43-423c-84da-d7458b10aea7

what helps to resolve the issue is to set your regional format setting to a specific region, and not a mix of regions.

So instead of setting your region format to English (Netherlands) set it either to Dutch (Nederlands) or English (United States)

To do this go to start, type in region, select *set regional format*

[image: type region, select set regional format]

Change the regional format drop down value, in this case English (Netherlands).

[image: regional format dropdown]

To a region that is know to work, in this case English (United States)

[image: working format]

Then close the settings windows and close your office programs, then start them back up. Then your visual basic should work again.

[image: everything back to normal]